# Angular 2 transform component input

Tags: angular

I have a component like

```
export class InspectionComponent {    
    @Input()
    inspections: Inspections[];
}
```

I'd like to group the inspections by a date property. Do I use or pipe or is there a way to transform the list in the component? I'm thinking an observable, but I can't figure out if it's possible to observe a component input?

Basically what I'd like to write is something like (I know this doesn't make sense, but it shows the point)

```
export class InspectionComponent implement OnInit {    
    @Input()
    inspections: Inspection[];

    groups: { date: Date, inspections: Inspection[] };

    ngOnInit() {
        inspections.groupBy(...).subscribe(groups => this.groups = groups);
    }
}
```

I've read on the [Angular Docs on Pipes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe-) that it is strongly recommended to do filtering and sorting in the component logic.

Comment: Where does `inspections` data come from? Where, when, how often do you want to transform?

Comment: It comes from an http service, so it's not changed often. I want to regroup the `inspections` list everytime it changes, and preferably in the component logic.

Comment: I don't think a pipe is a good idea here. What's the problem with the observable approach?

Comment: Well, basically just that `inspections` is not an observable. Would the input then have the type `Observable<Inspection[]>` and then I need to change the parent component to handle an observable instead of a regular array? It seems a little convoluted, I'd like it better if the `InspectionComponent` could just take a regular list and group it.

Answer (score 4):

You can make `inspections` a setter, this way, every time when `inspections` are updated, grouping is executed:

```
groupedInspections: Inspections[]
@Input()
set inspections(inspections: Inspection[]) {
  this.groupedInspections = ...
}
```

In the view you bind then to `groupedInspections`.

You should be aware that this is not called when items are added/removed to the passed array.

Comment: That seems great, but I do need to group when items are added/removed. I suppose I want to regroup everytime angular redraws.

Comment: "I want to regroup everytime angular redraws." that sounds expensive. If you don't need to group when items are added/removed, then the approach in my answer is probably the best fit.

Comment: Well, I don't really need to regroup whenever angular redraws, but I just need any changes in the `inspections` list to be reflected.